# Google+ Platform for Android - getCurrentPerson

Tags: android

I use the Google+ Platform for Android with

```
PlusClient plusClient = 
  new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

In the onConnected-Listener I want to read the data of the logged in user

```
@Override
public void onConnected() {
  super.onConnected();    
  Person person = plusClient.getCurrentPerson();
}
```

The method call getCurrentPerson returns null.
Has anyone managed to read the user-data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an OAuth 2 client ID and add your Android app's developer (and probably production) signing keys to it, as described in the [Google+ Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) guide.

I did the same thing but had not known to create the OAuth 2 client ID, and was getting null from that method (of course with no useful feedback in the logs). After creating the ID and adding my app's signing keys, the method returns an actual Person instance.

Even though you don't actually USE the client ID anywhere in your application, the act of adding your signing key in that interface apparently unlocks something on Google's servers and allows things to work.

Comment: Absolutely right! The combination of signing key signature and package name is used to look up the app to a specific project in the API console. This is what is checked to see which APIs have been enabled and so on, and to track the quota for the application.

Comment: So how can I make it work during development then? During development, I do not sign the application after every change before deploying it to my device/emulator. I only sign the application before releasing it in Google Play.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: @jogrimst you can also add your development key to the api console. Simply add it as a second key. If you select android, it actually has a link to instructions on how to get your debug key.

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through the setup steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to create an OAuth 2 client ID and add your Android app's developer (if you are releasing only add release key, otherwise development key will be enough) signing keys to it, as described in the Google+ Getting Started guide.
- If you upgrade your API Console to New one, Go To "Consent Screen" and add Product Name(this is required)
- Go to API Console "APIs & auth" -> "APIs" and enable "Google+ API"

it will work like a charm!!!