# Can't Sign In in Google+ Platform for Android

Tags: android, google-plus

This question is the same as this [Google+ Platform for Android - getCurrentPerson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15136160/1707547) but i didn't find the solution here.

**Here's the problem:**

`plusClient.getCurrentPerson()` always `returns null` from `onSignedIn(PlusClient plusClient) function`

I used the `PlusSampleActivity -> SignInActivity` from Google Play Services.
Is this a bug, or anyone here knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you setup a client ID for your application in the API console (https://code.google.com/apis/console)? When your app connects, its key fingerprint and packagename are used to look up a project from the console and check whether you have the Google+ API enabled, and enough quota to handle the request. If its not found, it looks like you have 0 quota so the request fails, which will give you null.

You can see the steps to follow here: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

Comment: sorry for late response. I was busy for a month. I set-up already the client ID and Enabled the Google+ API and also the Quota is set. I go back this problem by next month. Have some rush projects. Tnx by the way.

Comment: Cool. When you get back to it, what I would do as a next step is to get the access token via GoogleAuthUtil, and plug it into the tokeninfo endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=TOKEN_GOES_HERE - that will show you for the token what scopes it has access to, what client ID and so on. Make sure all that matches up with what you expect. 

If that all looks good, you can try debugging by setting the following flag: adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
See if anything looks unusual there.

Answer (score 0):

As was answered by Ian, you must setup your app hash key in the API console. But beware that after performing this setup it may take some time (sometimes few hours) before you can use it, so be patient.